# Who coined a term in art philosophy refering to the danger of looking at older art through the lens of modern art? And what is it?

Tags: aesthetics, art

For example looking at african art through the lens of picasso, or certain landscape artists as proto-abstract art. Something to do with anachronism, but it was a specific art historian/philosopher with a specific term.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm guessing it could be Hal Foster.  https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/778488.pdf?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: Picasso himself seems to be more sensitive than his critics, see quote by Picasso here referring to African objects as "sacred". Article by Christopher Jones:  https://medium.com/@chrisjones_32882/picasso-primitivism-and-the-rights-and-wrongs-of-cultural-appropriation-1f964fa61cee, Foster is also mentioned further down.  Sorry I can't give you an exact answer, you might want to read in Hal Foster.

Comment: "*In literary and historical analysis, [presentism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentism_(literary_and_historical_analysis)) is the anachronistic introduction of present-day ideas and perspectives into depictions or interpretations of the past... The Oxford English Dictionary gives the first citation for presentism in its historiographic sense from 1916, and the word may have been used in this meaning as early as the 1870s. The historian David Hackett Fischer identifies presentism as a fallacy*". In other words, nobody coined it, it came from colloquial use.